# Many Worlds locality and EPR experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, locality, epr-experiment

I've read in Sean Carroll's book (Something Deeply Hidden) that the Many-Worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics might be the only way to avoid instantaneous effects of entanglement, by having the branching expand from the branching-event at the speed of light. This makes sense to me, observers far away are still "single-copy", until the branching reaches them.

But if we think of the experiment with Alice and Bob and their entangled particles far away (which must have opposite spins), I'm not sure what to make of it. When A or B measures the electron, there's the branching and we have the two worlds with the two possible outcomes (feel free to correct me, that's just how I understood it).
Now from the measurement event we then get the branching expanding at the speed of light.

What I don't get is: if they both measure their electron at -almost- the same time (whatever that means, let's say before light can travel between them anyway), then how can we think about branching? We have 2 particles with 2 states each, but only 2 possible combinations (=>worlds), either up/down or down/up.
So if Alice measures up and Bob measures down, that's two measurements and two branching events, but the outcome is related (the "Alice up" world can only go with the "Bob down" world), so do the branches "join" halfway through? Is that two branching events in two different places for the same branch?

And even then, I'm not sure how this solves the problem of "how does the particle immediately know which state to take/which world to join", that still seems completely non-local to me.

Note: I'm aware that "worlds" are just a puny human interpretation, but I definitely don't have the mathematical skills to understand the rules at the bottom of it, therefore I'm just asking for "a way to think about it".

Comment: In case you're wondering what happened, I deleted my answer because I'm not happy with it. It didn't directly address the question that you asked. I might replace it later with something more to the point, if I can think of a concise way to do that.

Comment: I did superficially read it and appreciated it (was gonna respond later), I'm always interested in different takes on the subject, since it's probably the only way to reach the so coveted "way of thinking about it".But yeah, I'm also looking for a more concrete answer within the interpretation of many-worlds (especially with the two contemporary branches for the same branch). Although I have to say, the biggest question for me -whatever the interpretation (hidden variables aside)- is "how does the particle know what to be", but I guess no one's got that answer (yet).

Comment: We have never observed "instantaneous" physical effects on entangled quantum systems. That they can't happen follows directly from relativity. MWI in particular is the result of a misunderstanding of both the phenomenology of quantum systems and the theory that was designed to describe the actually observed physical facts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Carroll said, but I do not think that Many Worlds avoids non-locality in entanglement, at least not in this way you're talking about it (one can debate just what locality means). Since branching is ultimately an 'arbitrary' way of splitting a wave function as a sum of (practically) non-interacting terms, I don't believe there's much precise meaning in statements like "the branching expands from the branching event at the speed of light".

In the EPR case, imagine we have the combined two-particle system in the state (ignoring the normalization for simplicity)

$$|\uparrow \rangle_A |\downarrow \rangle_B + |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B $$

where the subscripts $A,B$ stand for Alice and Bob's particles. If Alice measures the spin of her particle, the universal wave function describing the situation really is

$$ |\text{Alice's detector measured} \uparrow \rangle |\uparrow \rangle_A |\downarrow \rangle_B + |\text{Alice's detector measured} \downarrow \rangle |\downarrow \rangle_A |\uparrow \rangle_B $$

The content of the No Communication theorem is that the information locally accessible to Bob (who has no access to $A$ or the dectector) *has not* changed. In this way locality is preserved -- you cannot use entanglement for communication.

However, the description is still non-local. *It only makes sense to speak of the state of both particles at once* (that's what entanglement is about). It's not that Bob's particle "knows" the result of Alice's measurement and won't contradict it. They have a combined state, and in that combined state there simply isn't a possibility of finding both up or both down.

There's still an uncomfortable non-locality here and it cannot be wished away - it ultimately becomes the violation of Bell's inequality, and this has been experimentally confirmed. Crucially, however, you can only attest that Bell's inequality has been violated once you compare the measurements of Alice and Bob, and so information must have had time to travel (respecting the speed of light limit). In this way quantum theory maintains a curious, but ultimately consistent, middle-of-the-road position between locality and non-locality.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanics can describe the evolution of a physical system in terms of the evolution of its Heisenberg picture observables. The observables of one system $S_1$ only become dependent on those of another $S_2$ if $S_1$ and $S_2$ interact and those interactions. So there is an entirely local account of what is happening in entanglement experiments in quantum theory.

For a particular system $S_1$ its observables in general have more than one possible value. When it interacts with another system $S_2$ the observables of each system become dependent on those of the other. This dependence carries some quantum information and that information spreads locally from one system to the other. In general copying information about an observable suppresses interference between different values of that observable: this is called decoherence. As a result there are multiple autonomous channels of information, one for each measured value

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

This branching is an entirely local process and other systems aren't branched by the results of these measurements until they interact with the branched system. So each system in an entangled pair branches locally according to the possible values of the measured observables. Quantum information is then carried in decoherent channels about the branching and the way one system branches relative to another is established when the results of those measurements interact:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

Talk of universes is an approximate description of this process that works pretty well in the circumstances of everyday life but breaks down badly in interference and entanglement experiments.

Comment: Quantum mechanics does not describe the evolution of one system. It describes the evolution of an ensemble of systems. That's exactly where MWI jumps off the tracks. If you read Everett's thesis, you can see in the first few sentences that he assumes that the wave function is the state of a single system. That is not what standard QM says and that is not how standard QM was constructed (linearity and unitarity follow naturally from an ensemble description but have to be postulated ad-hoc for single system "realism").

Answer (score -1):

Let's say physicists on planet x choose randomly a positron or an electron and send that particle up to space from the north pole. Then they send that particle's anti-particle up to space from the south pole.

Now an important thing is that the sent particle carries quite a lot of information about the planet.

If people on planet y observe that a positron was sent to their direction, then they know that in their branch the history of the planet x is such that an electron was sent to the opposite direction, at least if they discussed about the experiment with the people of the other planet.

So the planet y becomes entangled with the planet x. The way the two planets branch becomes correlated.

speed of propagation of branching = speed of propagation of information

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that analogy works for the question. Particle-Anti particle is "predetermined"; it's like putting a left glove and a right glove in the box and sending them out. With the spin (the usual example) there is no definite spin until you look, there's the superposition, and when you look (supposedly) there's a branching. That's what I'm wondering, a) what happens with two branching events for the same outcome (world) and b) how does the particle/branch "know" what spin to take/which world to "join". I'm not that interested in information exchange between observers here.

Comment: @Thaps1 It's not an analogy. It's a Schrodingen's cat -type of thing. Observer observes = observer decohores = observer splits.

Comment: I'm not sure it is though, when you send the particle it's already either a positron or an electron, but if you send eg. an electron, the spin is not already either up or down.