# Could polaroid filters with somewhat strange properties violate Bell's inequality without non-locality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Imagine a world where polaroid filters have somewhat strange properties, in such a way that this is impossible or very hard to know. The inhabitants use polaroid filters to determine what polarization photons have. The logic is kind of circular, they assume that polarization filters have symmetrical probability distributions because the filters are essential to define polarization in the first place.

Regarding Welt-an-sich, or what one would like to call the unmeasured reality, if we assume that there is a reality regardless of our measurements or our knowing, it is perhaps not suitable to talk about a probability distribution. The notion of a probability distribution perhaps derives its meaning from an empirical line of thinking. But let’s ignore that difficulty, and say, somewhat metaphorical, if you like, that polaroid filters can have a different probability distribution in and of them self, that it in principle could be very hard or impossible for us to discover (more or less, say, like it’s impossible to measure the one-way speed of light).

Let’s imagine that, not in a regular empirical sense, but in and of them self, polaroid filters have properties as these: If light is polarized horizontally (90°) relative to the polaroid filter, it never passes. If its polarization is vertical (0°) relative to the filter, it always passes. If it is oriented 30°, it passes with cos(30)= ca. 86,6% probability. If oriented 60°, it passes with cos(60)= 50% probability.

And then comes Alice and Bob. They do experiments with set ups that are typical for scientists who want to demonstrate violation of Bell’s inequality.

Could they be wrong about non-locality? Could we live in such a world?

(I would have preferred to ask the question in terms of spin entanglement, but found it too difficult. My hope was that polarization could serve as an analogy.)

Answer (score 2):

You write:

> But let’s ignore that difficulty, and say, somewhat metaphorical, if you like, that polaroid filters can have a different probability distribution in and of them self, that it in principle could be very hard or impossible for us to discover (more or less, say, like it’s impossible to measure the one-way speed of light).

The Bell inequalities assume that the outcomes of experiments on photons are described by local, stochastic variables (LSVs): numbers picked at random locally with a probability distribution that depends on the information in the measured system. Quantum mechanics predicts that the correlations found when the results of measurements on entangled particles are compared are larger than those allowed by a theory of LSVs.

Your theory is that somehow the measurement devices produce the results predicted by quantum mechanics. You haven't specified any theory that would produce this result. As such, your theory makes no predictions independent of those of quantum mechanics and so it isn't independently testable.

By the same token your theory doesn't explain how the correlations arise. Nor does it explain anything else. You might as well just say "shit happens" or "God did it". You're just taking quantum mechanics and slapping a new label on it. Also, the measurement devices somehow have to have information about how experimenters are going to interact with the measured system in advance of the experiment. How are they doing this? Are polarisation filters secretly controlling people by telepathic signals or something? Are the polarisation filters controlling you right now? Did they write your question? Are they writing my answer? You haven't put any limits on this process so there is no answer to any of these questions.

Bell's inequality implies that entanglement correlations can't be accounted for by LSVs, but quantum mechanics doesn't explain the experiment in terms of LSVs, but in terms of observables described by Hermitian operators. So Bell inequalties don't imply that quantum mechanics is non-local. There is a local quantum mechanical explanation of the correlations:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/798983/28512

Comment: @AtlantisVel (to your comment) The simple answer is No, it cannot have anything to do with the measurement apparatus. That's because you would not get perfect correlations when the measurement setting are the same. If the "polaroid" or whatever added something itself to the detection - let's say up to 2% one way or the other - then there would cases in which they added 2% one way for Alice, and sometimes 2% the opposite way for Bob. That's 4% total difference, which is easily noticeable in Bell tests. Perfect correlations (predicted by QM) are used for alignment in Bell tests.

Comment: If violation of Bell's inequality is taken to rule out an alternative such as mine, and this is not true, then this should be interesting in and of itself. Let's, for the sake of argument, assume that polarization filters are somewhat biased, so that they are easy going when incoming light beams are somewhat close to alignment, otherwise not. Could this explain such "strange" correlations as we observe? I think so. You are smarter than me, and could have calculated it, to see if that holds.

Comment: To be clear: This is NOT intended as a general argument against non-locality. But the devil is in the details, and any attitude as if non-locality (or quantum weirdness) is one big fat question, is not well suited for progress, in my opinion. The nuances are important.

Answer (score 0):

Polarization is spin for light (spin 1 photons), so that's perfectly fine.  The issue here is that you haven't properly accounted for Bell, which is the lynchpin for proof of quantum non-locality. Yes, you have Bell in the title.  A violation of a Bell inequality occurs because it is the relationship of the measurement settings chosen by Alice and Bob - while far apart - that dictates the correlation statistics.  Nothing else.

So if the choices made by Alice and Bob are incompatible with the idea that the entangled light was already polarized, there's your killer.  Experiments have been performed where Alice and Bob make there angle choices mid-flight.  See for example: [Violation of Bell's inequality under strict Einstein locality conditions](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810080) (1998) "*We observe strong violation of Bell's inequality in an Einstein, Podolsky and Rosen type experiment with independent observers... We for the first time fully enforce the condition of locality, a central assumption in the derivation of Bell's theorem. The necessary space-like separation of the observations is achieved by sufficient physical distance between the measurement stations, by ultra-fast and random setting of the analyzers...*"

So there is no chance that any lightspeed effect could lead to synchronization of results between Alice and Bob.  Don't forget: It is also a requirement that Alice and Bob have perfectly correlated results when their angle choices are the same.

In case that isn't convincing enough: It is possible to entangle a pair of photons that have never even existed in a common light cone.  I.e. they are created by independent sources far apart.  These violate Bell inequalities (such as CHSH) too.  The method of accomplishing this feat is called Entanglement Swapping. Check out:  [High-fidelity entanglement swapping with fully independent sources](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3991) (2008) "*Entanglement swapping allows to establish entanglement between independent particles that never
interacted nor share any common past. ... Here, we demonstrate entanglement swapping with time-synchronized independent sources with a fidelity high enough to violate a Clauser-Horne-Shimony-Holt [CHSH] inequality by more than four standard deviations.*"

Clearly, there is a nonlocal component of entanglement demonstrated by these and other ground-breaking experiments.  So no, quantum nonlocality has been well-studied and tested in hundreds of forms.

Comment: Did you understand the question? I was wondering if, let's say polarization filters are somewhat biased, could this explain observed correlations without invoking (physical) non-locality? Could such an assumption be consistent? It should be possible to calculate that, although I am not intelligent enough to perform it. You are, and could have checked it.

Comment: @AtlantisVel Your question mentions Bell Inequality & Nonlocality, I focused on that. You also include the idea that "If its polarization is vertical (0°) relative to the filter, it always passes... If oriented 60°, it passes with 25% probability." Yes, this is true for photons of polarized light. But pairs of unentangled vs entangled photons don't follow the same stats, precisely because entangled light has no prior polarization. A random mixture of unentangled light averages 25% correlation at identical angles for Alice & Bob (50% x 50%). Entangled light is 100%. Total intensity is the same.